# How to redirect multiple inputs from files to a binary being debugged in gdb?

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, buffer-overflow, exploit

The binary I am debugging in gdb first asks me for a id first and then if the id is valid asks for a second input.

```
gef➤  run

Agent ID : 48093572 //This is the first input which the user has to enter

Login Validated

Main Menu:

1. Extraction Points

2. Request Extraction

3. Submit Report

0. Exit

Enter selection:   // This is the second input the user has to enter
```

How can I pass both the inputs from a file using the '<' operator. If there was a single input I could have done it as

```
gef➤  run < input.txt
```

But the approach above is not working for multiple inputs.

*Note:- gef is an addon for gdb

Answer (score 3):

In case you haven't found the solution, or anyone else needs this bit of information, this worked for me:

```
gdb$ r < <(cat 1_intest.txt 2_intest.txt)
```

Each input gets passed to the program by cating the corresponding file's content.